# Microsoft.Graph get all users of a group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft.Graph and I want to return a list of all users in particular groups. I can not find any digestible information about this.

I have tried using `.Request().Expand(x => x.Members)` but this only returns 20 users. And they are not paged (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#expand)).

I can pull a list of groups fine, but how can I filter users based on what group they're in? This is what I've got so far...

```
public async Task Do()
{
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_authProvider);
    var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();

    do
    {
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{group.Id}, {group.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine("------");

            var filter = $""; // What goes here?
            var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter(filter).GetAsync();

            do
            {
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{user.Id}, {user.GivenName} {user.Surname}, {user.MemberOf}");
                }
            }
            while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    while (groups.NextPageRequest != null && (groups = await groups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this works

```
public async Task Do()
{
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_authProvider);

    var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();

    do
    {
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{group.Id}, {group.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine("------");

            var users = await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();

            do
            {
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{user.Id}");
                }
            }
            while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);

            Console.WriteLine("------");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    while (groups.NextPageRequest != null && (groups = await groups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
}
```

Comment: How do we get the User properties ? Like User PrincipalName and DisplayName?

Comment: @learntogrow-growtolearn I just came across the same issue and was able to extract the DisplayName by safely casting the user to Microsoft.Graph.User. Makes sure to safely cast as not all members are users! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it:

```cs
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>();
    queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));

    var groupMembers = await graphClient
        .Groups[groupId]
        .Members
        .Request(queryOptions)
        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
        .GetAsync();

    var users = new List<User>();
    users.AddRange(groupMembers.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());

    while (groupMembers.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        groupMembers = await groupMembers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        users.AddRange(groupMembers.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
    }
```