# Ms.Graph.Group API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-6.0, microsoft-graph-api

How can I loop the result view response of graph service client to a model?

I cannot find any property in the member to get the value of the array.

Thanks.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    var members =  graphClient.Groups["OBJectID"].Members.Request().GetAsync().Result;

    TempData["members"] = members.ToString();

    //var mem = members.AsQueryable().ToList();

    List<CRMUsers> _users = new List<CRMUsers>();

    foreach (var item in members)
    {
        _users.Add(new CRMUsers
        {
            GUID = item.AdditionalData["GUID"].ToString()
        }) ;   
    }
    // var Json = await getMembers();

    return View(members);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get groups via below code.

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();
```

We can get users in group like below code.

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Id}, {group.DisplayName}");

    var users = await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();
    ...
}
```

In your code, you want get `members` in group which `ID = OBJectID`.

You can try below code to get `members` object without `.Result`.

```
var members =  graphClient.Groups["OBJectID"].Members.Request().GetAsync();
```

**Related issue**

[Microsoft.Graph get all users of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300631/7687666)